# Best way to exchange matrix rows?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Working with two dimensional arrays, I want to find a way to avoid actually swapping rows of a matrix and just change the indices of the rows. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121149/how-to-sort-3d-array-in-c-with-each-row-is-specific-to-one-entry-if-1d-array) but the answer includes swapping the rows and seems to take just as much time.

and if there isn't any way to change the indices, what other way would you suggest for making row/column swapping less time consuming?

PS.
this is how I have defined the Matrix:

```
float[,] Ab = new float[,] 
            {
            {1,4,-2,104},
            {3,5,100,90},
            {2,-3,48,2},
            };
```

and I want it to be sorted by a vector like this: [3 2 1], so the result would be

```
Ab =    {
        {2,-3,48,2},
        {3,5,100,90},
        {1,4,-2,104},     
        };
```

Comment: You could probably write some code that uses pointers to make it faster.

Comment: When you say two-dimensional array... is it a rectangular or a jagged array?  Show us the code of how you defined the original, please.  Things will differ based on your implementation.  There's even a way to have a one-dimensional array act like a multidimensional array, so showing code is important.

Comment: @B.K. I will edit the post to do so, thanks.

Comment: Ah, so it's a rectangular two-dimensional array.  Would have been a lot easier if it was jagged... lol :)

Comment: On a side note, if you're after high performance, consider using a 1d array with manual computation of the index when accessing.  Multi-dimensional arrays have a lot of drawbacks in the CLR, including extra index bounds checks and reduced opportunities for jitter optimization.  It also lets you do things like iterate linearly in an index for performing a swap operation, rather than doing bounds checking and multiplication for every access in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>So, unfortunately for you, that answer you saw earlier is the only thing you can do in this situation, since you have a rectangular array.</strike> **(See edit below).**  You can't index into a specific row on its own in a rectangular array, as far as I know.

With a jagged array, you could do it very easily:

```
var Ab = new[]
{
    new float[] {1,4,-2,104},
    new float[] {3,5,100,90},
    new float[] {2,-3,48,2}
};

// Example swap (rows 0 and 1).
var temp = Ab[0];
Ab[0] = Ab[1];
Ab[1] = temp;
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to figure out a way to swap rows in a rectangular array (based on http://www.dotnetperls.com/buffer and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var Ab = new float[,]
{
    {1, 4, -2, 104},
    {3, 5, 100, 90},
    {2, -3, 48, 2}
};

// Size of float.
var floatSize = sizeof (float);

// Number of elements in a row.
var numRowElements = 4;

// Temporary array for an intermediate step in the swap operation.
var temp = new float[numRowElements];

// Copy first row into a temporary array.
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Ab, 0, temp, 0, numRowElements*floatSize);

// Copy second row into the first row.
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Ab, numRowElements*floatSize, Ab, 0, numRowElements*floatSize);

// Copy temporary array into the second row.
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, Ab, numRowElements*floatSize, numRowElements*floatSize);
```

Now, I used `float` because that's what you had in your original post, but I don't see floats being used in your arrays.  So, if you'll stick with integer values, I suggest using `int` instead of `float`.

Comment: Since this is the most important part of my code I can change the other parts and use jagged arrays in them too. Thank you very much for your response, this was really helpful :-)

Comment: @Lily Check out my edit.  It's a bit more involved, but works really well for a rectangular array.

Comment: Thank you! and yeah the initial numbers are int types but when calculations are done on them they might become non-int numbers and I need the float precision.

Answer (score 4):

Jagged arrays are usually faster, so you may want to switch to them anyway, but here's how to swap rows in a rectangular array:

Indirection!

> "Every problem in computer science can be solved by introducing another layer of indirection."

```
int[] rowInd = { 3, 2, 1 };
```

and from now one, you access

```
matrix[rowInd[i]-1, j] // take out the "-1" if you use zero-based numbering
```

instead of

```
matrix[i,j]
```

Swapping rows just involves changing `rowInd`.

As a bonus, this method works for swapping columns as well, and still works for swapping columns in jagged arrays:

```
matrixJagged[i][colInd[j]]
```

Comment: This is a decent solution for something like Gaussian elimination, which is a common algorithm that would require row swapping.  Would need to be profiled to see if it actually performs better than swapping the entire row (since it requires indirection on each access), but it might well be a helpful optimization.